# Probability theory: Cheating husband and subway

Tags: probability-theory

Here is the problem: 
 Man cheats on his wife, everyday after work. So when the work day ends he goes to a subway station and waits for a train. Here is a subway map:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o
Home                        |   Mistress
Station                     |   Station
                            |
                            workplace
```

The man waits for the first train to come and if the train goes in mistress's direction he cheats else he goes home. On both sides trains come and go with the same frequency. And trains never meet at station #8 
Question is: Will the man end up cheating or going home more often? and why?

Here is my solution: 
Will the man cheat more? yes.
why?
1)Since the trains come and go with same frequency, we can assume(to simplify the problem) that there is only one train that goes in circles.
2) To go home, the train has to be between (8)-9-8. And to go to mistress the train has to be between (8)-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8.

But my solution works only if the number of trains is less the number of stations. 
Does this problem has a solution? Is my logic in the right direction? 
Thank you for reading.

Comment: If a train goes in circles, won't it always be going in the same direction?

Comment: By circles I meant that stations go in order(for 3 stations) 
1-2-3-2-1-2-3... Think of circle around the map(which is a line).